# авторизация в веб-приложении через vk

Tags: vkontakte-api, авторизация

Есть веб-приложение, которое позволяет пользователям регистрироваться по email и активировать свою учетную запись по ссылке в письме. И есть приложение на android, которое общается с веб-приложением через json.

Цель - дать пользователям возможность регистрироваться и авторизовываться в нашем веб-приложении через вк. На android используется vk android sdk, при авторизации на клиенте получены user_id, token, и всякая персональная информация о пользователе(фио, пол, дата рождения и пр.).

Вопрос - имея эти данные, каким образом на сервере точно знать, что это валидные данные? Как обезопасить себя от запросов с рандомными данными, "похожими" на валидные? Ведь в случае регистрации по email нашим залогом валидности было обязательное подтверждение учетной записи по ссылке в письме. А при регистрации по вк такой схемы уже нет. Весь трафик от клиента до сервера открыт, не зашифрован, легко перехватывается любым сниффером(т.е передавать токен на сервер видимо не стоит).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да. Для авторизации Вам придется передавать на сервер token. Далее, серверу с этими данными нужно будет обращаться к методу secure.checkToken для проверки присланного пользователем токена. Само приложение должно быть зарегистрировано в ВК.

Если Вас беспокоит именно сам факт передачи токена, то можете:

1. использовать SSL/TLS для шифрования соединения. Никакой проблемы с
   этим быть не должно.
2. токен имеет срок жизни. Можете его периодически обновлять и
   реавторизироваться (но этот вариант не очень).
3. не думать о том, что кто-то сидит под Вашими дверями и пытается
   выцепить из всего трафика именно конкретный набор символов
   (ему заранее не известный). При этом тот кто сидит под Вашими
   дверями понятия не имеет по какому протоколу идет обмен, идет ли он
   вообще, пользуетесь ли Вы в этот момент программой, на каком порту
   соединение, в какой момент идет авторизация и т.д. и т.п. То что Вы
   сниффером можете увидеть данные вовсе не означает, что кто-то их
   сможет также легко увидеть и тем более не означает, что он сможет
   ими воспользоваться в данный момент (а при повторной авторизации см.
   пункт 2). В теории можно много чего нафантазировать, но вот на
   практике будет проще иголки под ногти загнать пользователю, чтобы
   узнать пароли доступа.